# Confused on Equivalence Relation

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

Was reading this article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation In the section "Connections to other relations" I am seeing the statement "Equality is both an equivalence relation and a partial order. Equality is also the only relation on a set that is reflexive, symmetric and antisymmetric. In algebraic expressions, equal variables may be substituted for one another, a facility that is not available for equivalence related variables. The equivalence classes of an equivalence relation can substitute for one another, but not individuals within a class."
Not sure what they mean by substitution here at end. I recall proving that in modulo arithmetic (an equivalence relation) that arithmetic was independent of representative that is we can always replace a value in an expression with another as long as they are in the same equivalence class. That is 22+3 modulo 3 can be replaced with 1+3 modulo 3.   Any help on what they mean?

Comment: Well, the fact that a substitution is valid in *some* algebraic relations doesn't mean it is valid in *all* of them. For instance $2^{22}-1\equiv 0 \pmod 3$ doesn't mean that $2^1-1\equiv 0 \pmod 3$.

Comment: I think the article is trying to say that the mere fact that equivalence mod $n$ is an equivalence relation doesn't imply that these sorts of substitutions are permitted. You had to prove that addition is well-defined mod $n$, for instance, in order to know that representatives of the same class can substitute for one another when performing addition mod $n$. In general, proving that functions/operations are well-defined on equivalence classes is quite a common (and sometimes nontrivial) task.

Comment: @Kenanski Bowspleefi I think I understand where you are coming from. Essentially the substitution property needs to be earned through proof rather then just assumed from the equivalence relation. So I shouldn't interpret the article in a strict sense.

Comment: @lulu  but I Can always replace 2 with any other element in the same equivalence let's say 5 and the answers will not change.

Comment: Not following.  Again $2^2\not \equiv 2^5 \pmod 3$.  The substitution only works under precise conditions.

Comment: I see your point also @lulu you can't replace exponents, even though 22 and 1 are in the same equivalence class they will give different results when using them as exponents.

Comment: what I meant also was 2ˆ5  is congruent to 5ˆ5 which is congruent to 8ˆ5 as 2,5,and 8 are in the same equivalence class modulo 3.

Comment: And, of course, not all relations are $\mod 3$ congruences.  $5\equiv 12\pmod 7$ but you obviously can't substitute $2$ for $5$ in that, even though $2\equiv 5\pmod 3$.  Equality is very, very strong.

Comment: I agree 1/2 =4/8 you would be able to substitute either interchangeably anywhere and not change the answer.